# Как лучше назвать класс, который получает информацию об объектах по их id?

Tags: рефакторинг, классы, имена

Как лучше назвать класс, который получает информацию об объектах по их id? такие как имя, значеня, отношения, но не сам объект

Comment: Поскольку объект и его id в некотором смысле равнозначны, по сути класс получает _проекцию_ класса на его свойство. То есть получается `Projection`.

Но я бы повёл рефакторинг дальше, и избавился бы вовсе от `id`. Зачем вам `id`, если можно вместо него передавать сам объект (или указатель на него)?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю зачем такие извращения. Если вы хотите получать инфо об объектах по их ИД, зачем вам создавать еще и класс адаптер для этого? Я так понимаю, у вас массив однотипных объектов, и надо найти в этом множестве объект с заданным ИД, вызывая у каждого getID(int id)? Чем отдельный класс здесь лучше прямого перебора в цикле?

Comment: @asianirish, а это, в самом деле, не широко ли известный список свойств?

--

Назовите, например, `IdObjInfo` или `IdObjProps`.

--

На практике, новый разработчик все равно будет вынужден читать документацию (или код реализации) для того, чтобы хорошо разобраться в программе. 

*То, что можно только читая мнемоники, понять программу -- это миф* (кочующий из одной книги в другую и каждый раз "подтверждаемый" идиотскими примерами).

А после изучения, сами названия уже не столь важны. Важно, что бы при просмотре участков кода от них: 

1) не рябило в глазах 

2) имена легко различались

Comment: @MDJHD для универсальности источника данных (не только ОЗУ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Осознал (с утра то), что делаю функционал QAbstractItemModel (qt). Назвал NodeModel и далее по иерархии.